# Replacing multiple bytes in a byte array

Tags: c#

I have a byte array like so

```
 var byteArray = new byte[]
        {
            0x9C, 0x50, 0x53, 0x51, 0x52, 0x41, 0x50, 0x41, 0x51, 0x41, 0x52, 0x41, 0x53, 
            0x48, 0x83, 0xEC, 0x28,                                                       
            0x48, 0xB9, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Line 3                 
            0x48, 0xB8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Line 4                  
            0xFF, 0xD0,                                                                   
            0x48, 0x83, 0xC4, 0x28,                                                       
            0x41, 0x5B, 0x41, 0x5A, 0x41, 0x59, 0x41, 0x58, 0x5A, 0x59, 0x5B, 0x58,0x9D,  
            0xC3                                                                          
        };
```

I want to replace the following bytes on line 3

```
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
```

As well as the following bytes on line 4

```
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
```

With different bytes (other than 0x00)

**Note** that the bytes I want to change on line 3 are **different** to the bytes I want to change on line 4

What is the simplest way to accomplish this?

Comment: can't you just edit the value?

Comment: Do you need a generalized solution? How do you identify the places where bytes should be replaced? What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: @david no I can't edit the array because the values I want to write into the array are determined from another source

Comment: [`Array.Copy(Array sourceArray, int sourceIndex, Array destinationArray, int destinationIndex, int length)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copy?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Array_Copy_System_Array_System_Int32_System_Array_System_Int32_System_Int32_) will work, assuming the number of bytes in source and destination is the same. You just need to have arrays containing the replacement bytes, and know the offset of the destination bytes.

Comment: @MatthewWatson are you recommending I write from the start of line 3 (0x48) to the end of line 4 and fill in the 0x00 bytes with the bytes I want in the array using Array.Copy()?

Comment: No - I mean you should make two calls to Array.Copy() (one for each set of replacement bytes) - but this assumes that you already know the offset of the destination bytes and have arrays with the replacement bytes available. However since the two sets of bytes to be replaced are contiguous, you *could* do that with just one copy, but that's not so clean.

Comment: Ah, right I understand what you're saying - Yes I know the offset of the destination bytes. I'll give it a go

Comment: You've focussed too much on giving us a *single example* without explaining what the *general pattern* is that you're trying to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want / can't modify your source array, you can easily create another one with same values :

```
byte[] copyArray;
byteArray.CopyTo(copyArray, 0);
// or
copyArray = byteArray.ToArray() // following @Matthew Watson
```

Then if you want to change your eigth last values for line 3 :

```
byte[] ReplaceThirdLineValues(byte[] source, params byte[] newValues)
{
    byte[] copyArray;
    byteArray.CopyTo(source, 0);

    for (int i = 0 ; i < newValues.Length && i < 8 ; i++)
    // i < 8 because in your array there are 8 0x00 in a row
        if (copyArray[19 + i] == 0x00 && newValues[i] > 0x00)
        // newValues[i] > 0x00, so if you do not want to override value,
        // just give 0x00 to your parameter
            copyArray[19 + i] = newValues[i];
}
```

For your fourth line, replace `copyArray[19 + i]` by `copyArray[29 + i]`

```
byte[] copyArray = ReplaceThirdLineValues(byteArray, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04);
```

Comment: Note that the easiest way to make a copy of an array (using Linq) is `var copyArray = byteArray.ToArray()`.